# C++ thread attach/dettach segfaults

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, multithreading, plugins

I use a plugin written in C++ for running queries on MySQL. It's used inside a Xojo (www.xojo.com) made application.

The problem is that if too many queries are executed too often it crashes on linux with a segmentation fault.

The plugin itself works by detaching from the calling thread before executing the query in order to not block the main application etc and then re-attaching once it's done. I think this re-attaching is the problem (gdb debugging in linux seems like this) but due to not having symbols on the Xojo's framework I'm not so sure.

This are the two methods/functions used for detaching and re-attaching

```
void ReattachCurrentThread(void *token)
{
    static void (*pAttachThread)(void*) = nullptr;
    if (!pAttachThread)
        pAttachThread = (void (*)(void *)) gResolver("_UnsafeAttachCurrentThread");
    if (pAttachThread) pAttachThread( token );
}

void * DetachCurrentThread(void)
{
    static void * (*pDetachThread)(void) = nullptr;
    if (!pDetachThread)
        pDetachThread = (void * (*)(void)) gResolver("_UnsafeDetachCurrentThread");
    if (pDetachThread) return pDetachThread();
    return nullptr;
}
```

And here is one place where those are called:

```
REALdbCursor MySQLPerformSelect(MySQLDatabaseData *db, REALstring queryStr)
{
    if (db->fConnection == nullptr) return nullptr;

    if (!LockDatabaseUsage( db )) return nullptr;

    REALstringData stringData;
    if (!REALGetStringData( queryStr, REALGetStringEncoding( queryStr ), &stringData )) return nullptr;

    void *detachToken = DetachCurrentThread();
    int err = mysql_real_query( db->fConnection, (const char *)stringData.data, stringData.length );
    ReattachCurrentThread( detachToken );
    db->CaptureLastError();

    REALDisposeStringData( &stringData );

    REALdbCursor retCursor = nullptr;
    if (0 == err) {
        // Allocate a cursor
        MySQLCursorData *curs = new MySQLCursorData;
        bzero( curs, sizeof( MySQLCursorData ) );

        curs->fCursor = new MySQLCursor( db );

        retCursor = NewDBCursor( curs );
    }

    UnlockDatabaseUsage( db );

    return retCursor;
}
```

My question is: is there anything wrong with **the code above** and is it expected to cause a segfault because it's not being careful somehow etc? I'm not a C++ programmer but it seems too *blunt* in my understanding, like not trying to see if thread is available first etc. Again, I'm not a C++ programmer so all I'm saying may be absurd etc...

The "whole" plugin's code is here:
[plugin's source](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3wycng6yd3617et/AABPT3yugEsbaPg-as1U_BQqa?dl=0)

Comment: `(void * (*)(void))` -- Avoiding type checking scares me.  It has multiple ways to screw up.

Comment: sure but it's not my code so I'm ok. :-) The segfaults appear to be related to thread priority though. What happens is that the threads calling this plugin's method had the lowest priority possible within a cooperative threads scheme. So, I think that when it was trying to re-attach it would "time out"(?) due to the thread taking <i>too long</i> to come back from sleeping etc. I've raised the thread's priority to highest right before calling the method and no more sigfaults for over 24 hours (it used to segfault every 10-15 minutes)

Comment: Might be wise to try to 'tame' the other threads.  The problem may raise its ugly head again someday.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems with the code:

1. The calls to `ReattachCurrentThread()`/`DetachCurrentThread()` are not synchronized
2. `UnlockDatabaseUsage()` is not always called: function `MySQLPerformSelect()` can return without calling `UnlockDatabaseUsage()`

The first problem can be fixed as follows:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex g_attachmentMutex;
void ReattachCurrentThread(void *token)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlg(g_attachmentMutex);
    static void (*pAttachThread)(void*) = nullptr;
    if (!pAttachThread)
        pAttachThread = (void (*)(void *)) gResolver("_UnsafeAttachCurrentThread");
    if (pAttachThread) pAttachThread( token );
}

void * DetachCurrentThread(void)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mlg(g_attachmentMutex);
    static void * (*pDetachThread)(void) = nullptr;
    if (!pDetachThread)
        pDetachThread = (void * (*)(void)) gResolver("_UnsafeDetachCurrentThread");
    if (pDetachThread) return pDetachThread();
    return nullptr;
}
```

The second problem can be fixed as follows:

```
class MySQLPerformSelectCleaner
{
    MySQLDatabaseData *_db;
public:
    MySQLPerformSelectCleaner(MySQLDatabaseData *db)
        : _db(db)
    {
    }
    ~MySQLPerformSelectCleaner()
    {
        UnlockDatabaseUsage(_db);
    }
};
REALdbCursor MySQLPerformSelect(MySQLDatabaseData *db, REALstring queryStr)
{
    if (db == nullptr || db->fConnection == nullptr) return nullptr;

    if (!LockDatabaseUsage( db )) return nullptr;
    MySQLPerformSelectCleaner c(db);

    REALstringData stringData;
    if (!REALGetStringData( queryStr, 
        REALGetStringEncoding( queryStr ), &stringData )) 
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void *detachToken = DetachCurrentThread();
    // perhaps a check for detachToken==nullptr is needed here
    int err = mysql_real_query( db->fConnection, (const char *)stringData.data, stringData.length );
    ReattachCurrentThread( detachToken );
    db->CaptureLastError();

    REALDisposeStringData( &stringData );

    REALdbCursor retCursor = nullptr;
    if (0 == err) {
        // Allocate a cursor
        MySQLCursorData *curs = new MySQLCursorData;
        bzero( curs, sizeof( MySQLCursorData ) );

        curs->fCursor = new MySQLCursor( db );

        retCursor = NewDBCursor( curs );
    }

    // Rely on the cleaner to call this: UnlockDatabaseUsage( db );
    return retCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `DetachCurrentThread()` always returns a pointer to a token? Add the below check and see if that helped:

```
void *detachToken = DetachCurrentThread();
if (detachToken == nullptr) return nullptr; // ensure the pointer to a token is returned before proceeding further.
```

Comment: yes, it returns the calling thread's so unless the calling application crashes between the call to the method and this Detach call it should alway return a pointer etc.
I think I may have found the solution though, still checking...

Answer (score 0):

If the code only crashes when there are too many queries running, you might want to check `_UnsafeAttachCurrentThread` and `_UnsafeDetachCurrentThread` for a race condition which could lead to a segfault. Perhaps `DetachCurrentThread` returns a nullptr if there are too many queries? You can add a check if `detachToken` is valid in that case.

Also, there can be a possible deadlock if `REALGetStringData` fails. Please call `UnlockDatabaseUsage` before returning.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is right here:

`if (db->fConnection == nullptr) return nullptr;`

The variable `db` is a pointer. You need to do a check before you evaluate this condition:

```
if (!db) 
{
    // throw error, return from function call, etc.
}
```